# How can I ensure that a disk image shared by someone is safe to use?

Tags: security, disk-image

I have downloaded and am using an Ubuntu image that someone has shared on GitHub (well, the torrent which I downloaded).

I am sure that this person's intentions are good and it seems like a very handy bit of software, but how do I know that they haven't left something in the image that will steal my credentials / wipe my data / use my equipment for mining (it is a mining rig and the image is a mining image so potential for mining for the image creator is high).

As I said I am sure that this person is honest. But it's quite a lot to trust a complete stranger with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fact is, unless you create the image yourself, you can not be sure if the image is compromised. It is safer to use the official Ubuntu image and make an normal install of it and the needed tools/applications for mining, since you're talking about money here. Or would you trust your bank account credentials another person you not know?

There are several possibilities here to achieve what you want:

1. Create an image yourself based on the official image with the applications needed included.

   - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization
2. A probably easier approach is, if you only have one machine to install it onto is doing a normal install and then install the needed tools for mining.

   - https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/index.html

If you really considering downloading this image and using it, you should at least do a very deep research on the person and the image, look for replies from others on the image, do a deep background check on the person himself etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cant be sure unless you know how to search for possible problems. Why not build similar "image" from scratch?